# Renaming folders and files inside it

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code above renames all files in a set of folders to looks like "File x at x levels deep" using its current file name details, but I want it to rename the folders of these files too to "Folder x at x levels deep", but it gives an error saying that the folder is already opened in another process. The comments above is what I did until now (without success), and the rest in working as wanted.

```
import os, re

def everydirectory(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        file_w_path = os.path.join(path, file)
        os.chdir(path)
        if os.path.isdir(file_w_path):
            os.chdir(file_w_path)
            # complete_folder_name = re.search("(deep)([0-9])(FOLDER)([0-9])", file)
            # deepness = complete_folder_name.group(2)
            # folder_number = complete_folder_name.group(4)
            # new_folder_name = "Folder {} at {} levels deep".format(folder_number, deepness)
            # new_folder_name_w_path = os.path.join(path, new_folder_name)
            # os.rename(file_w_path, new_folder_name_w_path)
            # print("Folder " + file_w_path + " renamed to " + new_folder_name_w_path)
            everydirectory(file_w_path)
        elif os.path.isfile(file_w_path):
            path = os.path.join(path, os.getcwd())
            extension = os.path.splitext(file_w_path)[1]
            complete_file_name = re.search("(deep)([0-9])(FILE)([0-9])", file)
            deepness = complete_file_name.group(2)
            file_number = complete_file_name.group(4)
            new_file_name = "File {} at {} levels deep{}".format(file_number, deepness, extension)
            new_file_name_w_path = os.path.join(path, new_file_name)
            os.rename(file_w_path, new_file_name_w_path)
            print("File " + file_w_path + " RENAMED TO " + new_file_name_w_path)

directory = input("Where is the files?")
everydirectory(directory)
```

I think the problem is that it renames the file after the programs renames the folder, making it "lose" the original location of the file. Could someone check out what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Here is the set of folders/files and how I wanted it to look after running the script: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/0B8pLYoI76JJiOEtpNzdaYVZrVXM

Comment: The usual approach to this sort of renaming task is to use recursion to work upwards from the bottom of the directory tree. Rename the contents of a directory, then rename the contents of its parent.

Comment: Try renaming the folder after the call to `everydirectory(file_w_path)` that way it is done with any files inside. Or maybe it should be `everydirectory(new_folder_name_w_path)` using the named path instead of the old path?

Comment: @PM2Ring How could I use recursion? I tried doing what you said of first renaming the files with a function and then renaming the folders but it still gives the same error. I read about os.walk(topdown=False), but could not undestand how to use it, is this what are you talking about?

Comment: If you look at the answer below you will see an example of a recursive solution to your problem. @setti7

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code a bit in order to make it work. I also kept track of the `deep` in the recursion, but you could also rely on your filenames if you prefer:

```
import os, re
import os.path
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def change_dir(directory):
    wd = os.getcwd()
    try:
        os.chdir(directory)
        yield directory
    finally:
        os.chdir(wd)


def rename_file(filename, deep, is_dir=False):
    if is_dir:
        complete_filename = re.search("(deep)([0-9])(FOLDER)([0-9])", filename)
        file_number = complete_filename.group(4)
        new_filename = "Folder {} at {} levels deep".format(file_number, deep)
    else:
        complete_filename = re.search("(deep)([0-9])(FILE)([0-9])", filename)
        file_number = complete_filename.group(4)
        extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        new_filename = "File {} at {} levels deep{}".format(file_number, deep, extension)

    os.rename(filename, new_filename)


def every_directory(path, deep=0):
    deep += 1
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        is_dir = False
        filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            every_directory(filepath, deep)
            is_dir = True
        with change_dir(path):
            rename_file(file, deep=deep, is_dir=is_dir)
```

Comment: I'm starting to program with python and have never seen this "@contextmanager", what does it do?

Comment: The `contextmanager` is just a convinient decorator that can be used to define a function that can be used with a `with`-statement without needing to create a class or separate __enter__() and __exit__() methods. Have a look at decorators, the with statement in python if you want to learn more. When you grasp these 2 things, you can have a look at the documentation for contextlib: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html

Comment: Thank you! I already almost solved my problem without using decorators (haven't learn about them yet). But I'm stuck now: my "fixed" new script isn't changing the file names of the first folder (of the main folder, not the deep1FOLDER1), and I don't know why. Could you see it for me?  More in this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B8pLYoI76JJiT2I5YTVXb2t6RjQ)